# how do I prove this by induction? (recursion)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, closed-form, recursion

The terms are given recursively:
$P_0=3$
$P_1=7$
and $P_n = 3P_{n-1}-2P_{n-2}$ for $n\ge2$

What should I assume and what step proves that $P_n=2^{n+2}-1$ is a closed form of the sequence.

Suppose $n_0=1$ and the base cases are $0$ and $1$.

I think this book has a mistake

[problem from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7dEt.png)

Comment: The book has not made a mistake: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%3D3a%5Bn-1%5D-2a%5Bn-2%5D,a%5B0%5D%3D3,a%5B1%5D%3D7

Comment: If you want a straight check:  we have $3P_{n-1}-2P_{n-2}=3\times 2^{n+1}-3-2\times 2^n+2=6\times 2^{n}-2 \times 2^n-1=4\times 2^n-1=2^{n+2}-1=P_n$.

Comment: $P_n=3P_{n-1}-2P_{n-2}$ has corresponding characteristic polynomial $x^2-3x+2$ which factors as $(x-2)(x-1)$ and thus you will have $P_n = \alpha\cdot 2^n + \beta\cdot 1^n$ for some appropriate values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are found using the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2^{0+2}-1=2^{2}-1=4-1=3$ and $2^{1+2}-1=2^{3}-1=8-1=7$,
so that the base case holds. Suppose now that the statement holds
for $P_{n-1}$ and $P_{n-2}$ and note that
\begin{align*}
P_{n} & =3P_{n-1}-2P_{n-2}\\
 & =3\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)-2\left(2^{n}-1\right)\\
 & =3\cdot2^{n+1}-3-2^{n+1}+2\\
 & =2\cdot2^{n+1}-1\\
 & =2^{n+2}-1.
\end{align*}